# Madwimax: modem connecting but no internet

Tags: networking, internet

I'm using the [madwimax](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/madwimax) package to connect a Samsung USB modem to the internet. It has worked well before, on previous versions of Ubuntu, but now that I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 I have had problems connecting. Here's what I have:

From my syslog, I see that the modem connects to well to the internet:

```
$ tail syslog
Nov 25 19:22:56 server_name kernel: [ 7643.313567] usb 1-1: >New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6761
Nov 25 19:22:56 server_name kernel: [ 7643.313585] usb 1-1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Nov 25 19:22:56 server_name kernel: [ 7643.313598] usb 1-1: >Product: Samsung USB mWiMAX Modem 
Nov 25 19:22:56 server_name kernel: [ 7643.313609] usb 1-1: >Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS Co.Ltd.
Nov 25 19:22:56 server_name kernel: [ 7643.320211] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-1:1.1
Nov 25 19:23:02 server_name dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wimax0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Nov 25 19:23:02 server_name dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX on wimax0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Nov 25 19:23:02 server_name dhclient: DHCPOFFER of XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Nov 25 19:23:02 server_name dhclient: DHCPACK of XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Nov 25 19:23:02 server_name dhclient: bound to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -- renewal in 4311 seconds.
```

I see nothing weird in dmesg:

```
[ 6311.413438] scsi 3:0:0:0: >CD-ROM            Samsung  Install Disk     0.10 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 6311.445249] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[ 6311.445920] sr 3:0:0:0: >Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 6311.446619] sr 3:0:0:0: >Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[ 6311.455124] sr0: Hmm, seems the drive doesn't support multisession CD's
[ 6311.485119] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 6311.485629] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 6311.485644] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 6509.366803] usb 1-1: >USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 6739.568110] usb 1-1: >new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[ 6739.701153] usb 1-1: >New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6761
[ 6739.701171] usb 1-1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6739.701184] usb 1-1: >Product: Samsung USB mWiMAX Modem  
[ 6739.701195] usb 1-1: >Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS Co.Ltd.
[ 6739.710107] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-1:1.1
[ 6740.709747] scsi 4:0:0:0: >CD-ROM            Samsung  Install Disk     0.10 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 6740.741201] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[ 6740.741873] sr 4:0:0:0: >Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 6740.742613] sr 4:0:0:0: >Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[ 6740.755544] sr0: Hmm, seems the drive doesn't support multisession CD's
[ 6740.781039] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 6740.781357] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 6740.781366] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 6964.229412] type=1400 audit(1353885097.721:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=14883 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6964.930207] type=1400 audit(1353885098.421:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=14882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6964.934760] type=1400 audit(1353885098.425:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=14882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6964.935108] type=1400 audit(1353885098.425:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=14882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6965.218809] type=1400 audit(1353885098.709:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=14885 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6966.215718] type=1400 audit(1353885099.705:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=14933 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6966.929916] type=1400 audit(1353885100.421:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=14932 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6966.930401] type=1400 audit(1353885100.421:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=14932 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6966.930743] type=1400 audit(1353885100.421:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=14932 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 6967.212826] type=1400 audit(1353885100.705:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=14935 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 7098.436770] r8169 0000:02:00.0: >eth0: link down
[ 7098.436793] r8169 0000:02:00.0: >eth0: link down
[ 7098.437360] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 7100.029494] r8169 0000:02:00.0: >eth0: link up
[ 7100.030390] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 7408.143352] usb 1-1: >USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 7643.180108] usb 1-1: >new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[ 7643.313567] usb 1-1: >New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6761
[ 7643.313585] usb 1-1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 7643.313598] usb 1-1: >Product: Samsung USB mWiMAX Modem  
[ 7643.313609] usb 1-1: >Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS Co.Ltd.
[ 7643.320211] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-1:1.1
```

When I run the madwimax command, I see no errors either:

```
$ madwimax -v
Bus 001 Device 006: ID XXX:XXXX
Device found
Claimed interface
Chip info: cmc730_v2.1
Firmware info: u200_rev1-2.9.50-DA15
MAC: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Allocated tap interface: wimax0
```

Although, I do not see the IP appearing here. I normally saw the IP connection appear, but I now only see that in the syslog, and it is confirmed by ipconfig:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXXX  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::201:c0ff:fe05:b366/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38986 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:80731178 (80.7 MB)  TX bytes:3893255 (3.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:304270 (304.2 KB)  TX bytes:304270 (304.2 KB)

wimax0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Bcast:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: XXXXXXXXXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1386  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:698 (698.0 B)  TX bytes:1082 (1.0 KB)
```

I also flushed any iptables rules:

```
$ iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If I plug this USB modem into another computer, it connects just fine. Anybody any ideas?

Comment: Is there an auth/password token that you have to create to authenticate? Could you be missing this?

Comment: No, no password whatsoever. Internet works fine if I plug it into another Linux computer (Arch Linux).

Comment: What does `route` tell you?

Comment: Try list the routes and then you will see, if you don't have default gateway twice, or you can try ping to the default gateway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your default routing gateway correctly uses the gateway of the modem.  Try a traceroute, does it complain about no route to host?